# Player death/ game over c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been looking around and everyone seems to end the game by moving to another scene, I have this working atmosphere but I would like a more Fancy system.

My aim is to once the player dies to phase into an image with some UI text with scores etc and retry button.The problem I'm having is that my carries on running in the background.

Is there a way to stop everything but allow menus to still function? This includes spawning, Gravity, movement and other such things as my score is based on distance traveled.

I did read somewhere about game States but I'm not sure how those work of even if they could help.

Answer (score 2):

Looking up online i figured it should be something like stopping rendering, breaking out a game loop, or just stop processing.  I did find this [Make game stop](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/578798/make-the-game-stop-if-you-get-hit-by-enemy-object.html) which states

```
Time.timeScale = 0; // this will freeze the game, stop
```

Does this help?

Comment: I've used a mixture of this with custom gameOver and Pause functions